# Context menu in Outlook 2007 for links to open in my choice of browsers

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to have the context menu of links provide me an option to open in different browsers, rather than open in my default browser.  For instance,

Open in -->

- IE
- Firefox
- Opera
- Chrome
- Safari
- etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.  It looks like I can't, according to the fine folks at Microsoft.

> In Office Outlook 2007, only the following context menus have events associated with them:
>
> - Attachment context menus
> - Folder context menus
> - Item and selection context menus
> - Shortcut context menus
> - Store context menus
> - View context menus

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206752.aspx